# Run jquery lazy load on page load not scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, lazy-loading, jquery-isotope

I am trying to use the [jQuery lazy load plugin](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) with the [jQuery Isotope plugin](http://isotope.metafizzy.co).  Things seem to be playing together nicely, however, I am having a tough time figuring out how modify the lazy load plug in to my needs.

The plug in defaults to handling the scroll event to trigger lazy loading.  There is also hover and click.  I would like the plugin to fire on page load. Say, 2000ms after `$(window).load()` has completed.

I see I can create my own event functions per the documentation like so:

```
$(function() {          
    $("img:below-the-fold").lazyload({
        event : "sporty"
    });
});
$(window).bind("load", function() { 
    var timeout = setTimeout(function() {$("img.lazy").trigger("sporty")}, 5000);
});
```

However, due to my ignorance, I cannot see how I would work with this snippet to create my own page load event.

I would like the initial images to lazy load after `$(window).load()`, then when I apply isotope filtering events, the new items to be lazy loaded as they populate the DOM.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: That code snippet is pretty straight-forward. I don't understand well what you are not getting. By the way, what do you mean when you say "the new items" ?

Comment: The syntax of the snippet above throwing me for a loop as to how i can specify my function and call it appropriately.

As for the 'new items' - isotope is hiding many elements from the page on load.  When someone clicks a filtering option, some of the hidden items are shown and animated into position.

Comment: I still don't understand why would you need a loop. I suggest you to use a jQuery selector over all the images you want to lazy load and bind them to the load event, just as in the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a lazy load plugin that might help. Once initialized you can just call `$.fn.lazyloadanything('load')` and it will auto load without having to scroll first. No need to customize. Check it out:

https://github.com/shrimpwagon/jquery-lazyloadanything